# excluding the value of some frequency in a Fourier Transform

Tags: fft, ifft

I have a variable in time and I calculated its mean which is 9.5.
I have done the Fourier Transform of this variable, using the FFT in matlab.
I would like to consider only a range of frequencies, so I substituted with zero all the frequencies that I have excluded.
After this I did the ifft of this, obtaining again a variable in time. I calculated its mean and now is 9.5.
I am surprised because I supposed that it should have been a lower value because the signal does not include some frequencies.

Maybe substituting with 0 the value in the frequencies that I don't want to include is not the right procedure. Can you help me?

Comment: Don't zero out FFT bins to filter. You can convolve the signal with a sine wave and it's equivalent to multiplication a delta function in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pictures to follow] Let us start with a thought experiment (which can be simulated): imagine a constant signal with value $c$. Add a full period of a pure sine with non-zero frequency. If you can remove this harmonic contribution by zeroing out its frequency bin in the Fourier domain, then the resulting inverse Fourier signal will still have mean $c$. So remove "some frequency" does not reduce the mean *per se*.

Now remember that, in the Fourier domain, the "O-th" frequency ought to be equal (up to a constant scale factor) to the average of the signal. This is consistent with the above. The pure sine period has equally distributed values above and below $0$, so this does not contribute to the signal's average.

Then,  imagine that the observation time frame only encloses the first positive half of the "one-period sine", or the second one. Zeroing its frequency will sure remove frequency components, yet parts of the "not-otherwise" compensated sine bumps may remain, and modify  the amplitude, both ways. Therefore, if everything has been done right, your experiment is not totally surprising.

Finally: if removing or cancelling frequency terms in an FFT was a generic cure (*panacea*), I would not have the my job, and this site would be leaner. [As suggested by @ZRHan](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76387/excluding-the-value-of-some-frequency-in-a-fourier-transform#comment162511_76387), to zero out FFT coefficients is quite dangerous.